# embed in scroll view functionality in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In XCode, if you want to place the entire views hierarchy inside a scroll view you can select the root view and select the "Editor -> Embed in Scroll view" menu item.

Is this functionality present in Android Studio?
If not what is the easiest way to accomplish this?

I searched for it and couldn't find anything about it.
I'm using Android Studio 0.4.2

Thanks in advance,
Ido